# hello, I'm new to salesforce and I'm having trouble trigger the Employee__c parent object with the Contact parent object

Tags: apex, trigger

im edited my code and managed to insert and update the parent and child object through the trigger. now I need to do the delete trigger.

obs: I used secondId _c to receive the id of the parent to make the comparison with the child and be able to specify which child object will be edited.

and thasts my code

```
trigger objectsPageTrigger on Employee__c (after insert, after update, before delete) {

    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){
        triggerObjectsPage.convertUpsert(Trigger.new);
    }
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
        triggerObjectsPage.convertUpdate(Trigger.new);
    }
    // if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isDelete){
    //     triggerObjectsPage.convertToDelete(Trigger.oldMap);
    // }
}
```

```
public with sharing class triggerObjectsPage {

    public static void convertUpsert(List<Employee__c> empList){
        System.debug('upsert empList: ' + empList);
        List<Contact> newContact = new List<Contact>();

        if(empList.size() > 0 ){
            for (Employee__c employee : empList) {
                Contact contact = new Contact();

                contact.SecondId__c = employee.Id;
                contact.FirstName = employee.Name;
                contact.LastName = employee.LastName__c;
                contact.Gender__c = employee.Gender__c;
                contact.Birthdate = employee.BirthDate__c;
                contact.Profession__c = employee.Profession__c;
                contact.Salary__c = employee.Salary__c;

                newContact.add(contact);
            }
            saveContact(newContact);
        }
    }
    
    public static void saveContact(List<Contact> contact){
        system.debug('SAVED CONTACT: ' + contact);
        upsert contact;
        // for(Contact ctt: contact){
        //     String cttId = ctt.Id;
        //     System.debug('SAVEcttID: ' + cttId);
        // }
    }

    public static void convertUpdate(List<Employee__c> empList){
        System.debug('empList to update: ' + empList);
        List<Contact> updtContact = new List<Contact>();
        List<Contact> getContact = [SELECT Id, SecondId__c, FirstName, LastName, Birthdate, Profession__c, Gender__c, Salary__c FROM Contact WHERE SecondId__c != ''];

        if(!getContact.isEmpty()){
            for(Employee__c employee : empList){
                    for (Contact Contact : getContact){   
                        if (contact.SecondId__c == employee.Id){

                            contact.FirstName = employee.Name;
                            contact.LastName = employee.LastName__c;
                            contact.Gender__c = employee.Gender__c;
                            contact.Birthdate = employee.BirthDate__c;
                            contact.Profession__c = employee.Profession__c;
                            contact.Salary__c = employee.Salary__c;

                            updtContact.add(contact);
                            System.debug('contact To Update: ' + contact);
                        }
                    }
                }  
            updateContact(updtContact);
        }
    }
    
    public static void updateContact(List<Contact> contact){
        system.debug('UPDATED CONTACT' + contact);
        update contact;
    }
    
                // now I'm going to do this part
                
    // public static void convertToDelete(List<Employee__c> empList){
        
    // }

    // public static void deleteContact(List<Contact> contact){
    //     system.debug('deletedContact: ' + contact);
    //     delete contact;
    // }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code above? How is it not working? What errors are you receiving?

Comment: Follow-up question, is the `SecondId__c` field on `Contact` marked as an External ID ?

Comment: And please [edit] your question to add details instead of making it a comment. Comments are limited in length and formatting options, and are harder to read. They're best for asking clarifying questions. Keeping all the information in the body of the question itself is the way to go.

Comment: and thanks for the comments, they will help in future doubts or posts

Answer (score 0):

This code will not work because you are calling the same method from before insert and after update. In before insert, employee.Id field is not available. and you are using this Id field in the convertUpsert method. Also, what is the use of List getId , You have not used it anywhere in the code.